# Use JPA Spring boot with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, spring-boot

I want to use JPA in Spring boot with SQL Server by STS
This is my table:

[image]

MAVEN

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.hynnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc-chs</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-  name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=quanlybanhang
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER
```

Model.Account.class

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="taikhoan",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {    "tendangnhap" }) )
 public class Account {
 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int id;
 @NotNull

private String tendangnhap;
@NotNull
private String matkhau;
public Account(String tendangnhap, String matkhau) {
    super();
    this.tendangnhap = tendangnhap;
 this.matkhau = matkhau;
}
public Account() {
    super();
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTendangnhap() {
    return tendangnhap;
}

public void setTendangnhap(String tendangnhap) {
    this.tendangnhap = tendangnhap;
}
public String getMatkhau() {
    return matkhau;
}
public void setMatkhau(String matkhau) {
    this.matkhau = matkhau;
}   
}
```

interface AccountDAO

```
public interface AccountDAO extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer>{

}
```

ServiceAccount.class

```
@Service
public class ServerAccount {
    @Autowired
    AccountDAO server;
    public void them(Account acc){
        server.save(acc);   
    }
    public List<Account> lietke(){

        return server.findAll();    
    }
}
```

ServicesAccount.class

```
@Service
public class ServerAccount {
    @Autowired
    AccountDAO server;

    Account acc=new Account("khang", "1");

    public void addAccount(){
        server.save(acc);
    }


    public List<Account> lietke(){

        return server.findAll();    
    }

}
```

I called method addAccount() in Controller and this is Exception I got

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"

Please help me fix this exception. Thanks!!!

Comment: does your pom has 
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>xxxxx</version>
    </parent>

Comment: Yes my pom.xml had it.Before I worked with mySQL and it hadn't any exception or problem but when work with SQLServer I got there exception

Answer (score 0):

From your dependencies you missed (check you java version you use):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.2.jre8-preview</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and into the application properties correct this line:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-  name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Comment: property spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect has been updated to spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect